# Heap corruption error while deallocating array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem while running my code in c++. I have a function and I dynamically defined a two dimensional array in it using this code:

```
double** childs=new double *[2];
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
     childs[i]=new double[node];
```

The code worked good until I decided to deallocate that array at the end of function, I used code below:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    delete []childs[i];

delete [] childs;
```

After adding this part of code, I have problem while running and a debug error appeared as the picture below:

[image]

I searched a lot but I didn't figure out what is the problem. I know this error is for deallocating part because when I delete that part code works good.

Can anybody please help me on this?
Thanks very much

Comment: A for with no braces and no indentation, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: You're probably writing out of bounds of the allocated arrays. Or some other arrays.

Comment: And what's wrong with [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: The error message is "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory before start of heap buffer". You probably wrote something to `childs-1`, `childs[0]-1`, or `childs[1]-1`. Without seeing the rest of your code, it is hard to say which one.

Answer (score 2):

"I know this error is for deallocating part because when I delete that part code works good." -> That is not necessarily true. If you mess with memory, things can break at unexpected places. For example, maybe at some point of your code you are writing outside your array, and,  however, it breaks when it tries to delete[].

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is hustle over to the microsoft site and grab the debugging tools for windows. I'll wait...

Use gflags with the pageheap option. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561(v=vs.85).aspx

Pageheap will change the allocator for your process with one that puts protected pages before and after each allocation, as well as freed blocks. The upshot of this is that you will be able to detect when you  access outside the boundaries of your allocated data instantly by pagefault.

Obviously, you want to run your app under the debugger to trap that fault and figure out what you are doing wrong. Also, note it is better to do this with a release build, because the debug build will have guard bytes around the memory allocations that do not have the pageheap protection, so you can get a false negative when testing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is no enough code that to determine where the memory was overwritten, But you can find this place in the program simply by inserting printing statements that will print all pointers' values.

For example

```
std::cout << childs << std::endl;
std::cout << childs[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << childs[1] << std::endl;
```

Or you can try the following

```
std::cout << ( void * )( ( char * )childs - sizeof( int ) ) << std::endl;
std::cout << ( void * )( ( char * )childs[0] - sizeof( int ) ) << std::endl;
std::cout << ( void * )) ( char * )childs[1] - sizeof( int ) ) << std::endl;
```

Or you can use a loop to output childs[0] and childs[1] in the loop.:)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have code that wrote to the "guard bytes" of the allocated space, and the debug version of your Visual C++ application detected you did this.

What are "guard bytes"?  They are bytes written with information before and after the allocated space, and are initialized to some value by the runtime.  When it comes time to deallocate the memory, the runtime checks these guard bytes to see if the value has changed.  If they have changed, then you made a mistake somewhere where you inadvertantly wrote data into the area occupied by these bytes.

The Visual C++ runtime cannot, on the fly, detect when you wrote to the guard bytes.  It can only detect this when the deallocation is done.  That is why you believed your program "worked correctly", when in fact, it is not working correctly.

So look for overwrites by checking your array indices for negative values or positive values that exceed the bounds of your array.